# How to find/replace characters in a folder name?

Tags: find, directory, rename

I want to perform the following operations:

- Find/replace (using regexp) all occurrences of `<>:"\|?` and replace it with an empty string
- Find/replace (using regexp) all occurrences of `^\.+|\.+$` and replace it with an empty string

As a test, I manually created 2 folders (see screenshot) and ran these:

```
find "/home/users/Downloads/test" -regextype sed -regex "*<>:\|?*" -type d
find "/Users/chiyo/Downloads/test" -regextype sed -regex "*[<>:\|?]*" -type d
find "/Users/chiyo/Downloads/test" -regextype sed -regex "[<>:\|?]" -type d
```

and didn't find any.

I'm using this version of `find`.

```
=> find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.6.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Any ideas how this can be done?

[image: screenshot showing directories]

Comment: @AndyDalton apologies for not providing example the first time. edited.

Comment: `"*<>:\|?*"` looks closer to a shell glob than a regular expression - are you sure you understand the difference?

Comment: I don't see regextype of `sed` (mine is `find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2`)

Comment: They are directories not folders (There is a good reason for this. an Item (file/directory) can be in more than one directory. In real life we can be in more than one directory, but not in more than one folder.)

Comment: Do you have larry wall `rename` on you system? (Run `which rename`, follow the bread crumbs, the have a look in-side. If it starts `#!/usr/bin/perl`, then probably yes.)

Comment: I see that you have not accepted an answer. Does one of the answers below, solve your problem? or do you need more help?

Answer (score 4):

The first two examples are way out.

- `*<>:\|?*` You can not start with a `*`. `*` means 0 or more of the previous atom. It also says `<` followed by `>` followed by `:` …, and `?` is a special character.
- `*[<>:\|?]*` This is closer you are using a character class, but still the `*` at the start.
- `[<>:\|?]` This would match if it was a sub-regex match, but it is not. You need to match the entire filename, including directory path.

Therefore add regex codes to consume stuff before and after. ( `.` is any character, `*` is zero or more assurances of previous atom. Therefore `.*` will match anything.)

Therefore try `.*[<>:\|?].*`

You are not going to replace anything like this, and you have not told us what you want them replaced with.

Comment: OP wants to replace the matched pattern with an empty string. I've now edited the question to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

Use `-name` rather than `-regex` (since it's the filenames you are actually interested in and `-regex` matches against the whole path):

```
find folder -type d -name '*[<>:\|?]*'
```

This would find any directory in or beneath `folder` whose name contains at least one of  the characters `<`, `>`, `:`, `\`, `|` or `?`.

To remove these characters from the directory names:

```
find folder -depth -type d -name '*[<>:\|?]*' \
    -execdir bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1//[<>:\|?]/}"' bash {} ';'
```

This assumes that the new name of a renamed directory is not already the name of an existing directory. Adding a test for name clashes:

```
find folder -depth -type d -name '*[<>:\|?]*' \
    -execdir bash -c '[ ! -e "${1//[<>:\|?]/}" ] && mv "$1" "${1//[<>:\|?]/}"' bash {} ';'
```

This would avoid trying to rename a directory if the new name already exists

The `mv` command is executed within a `bash` child shell.  The shell is executed with the parent directory of the found directory as its working directory.  It's using a `bash`-specific parameter substitution to delete all the offending characters from the filenames of the found directories.

The command also uses `-depth` to do a depth-first traversal of the directory structure under `folder`.  Without this, `find` would try to enter directories that you just have renamed, and would fail.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Comment: Note `-name` uses globs, not regex. However **some** of the glob syntax is very similar to regex. I.e. character classes.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Except for when negating them, yes. In this specific case, there does not seem to be a need for regular expressions.